# Android (MultiSelect-)ListPrefernce disable entries

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference, android-multiselectlistpreference

Struggeling hard to get a multiselectlistprefernce to have some entries prechecked and/or disabled.

Found some solutions for implementing a custom eg. CheckboxPreference with a custom layout files. But IMHO this will not work with ListPreferences, as they have a dynamic size.

Is it possible to extend a MultiSelectListPreference and get checkbox and label at certain position to call textview#enabled or checkbox#setchecked?

I made a mock to illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use AlertDiaolg.multiselect and can achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Just extend `Preference` and show a custom `DialogFragment` with a `RecyclerView` and two different view-types (or drop that mock-up into there); then one can inflate either an enabled or disabled layout - or change each card-view, depending on other values. Within a `PreferenceScreen` it is all rather rigid and limited, but not when displaying a `DialogFragment`.